# LEFT JOIN two and more tables in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-custom-function

Say I have two tables. Table A (material requirements):

```
product_id | material | required
1          | A        | 0.5
1          | B        | 0.7
2          | A        | 0.2
3          | A        | 0.12
```

And Table B (orders):

```
order_id | product_id | quantity
1        | 1          | 100
2        | 2          | 10
```

I want to do a `LEFT JOIN`* on these two tables (table B being outer), such that the result would be:

```
order_id | product_id | quantity | material | required
1        | 1          | 100      | A        | 0.5
1        | 1          | 100      | B        | 0.7
2        | 2          | 10       | A        | 0.2
```

How do I do this? Of course, the end goal is to multiply the `required` with the `quantity`

Ideally, there should be an additional table with just basic product information, e.g. something like:

```
product_id | name | description
```

*It should be `LEFT JOIN`, NOT `INNER JOIN` simply because all `orders` should be shown, even if the info in product material description is not yet input. An order cannot be 'forgotten' because inner join is used.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 6):

- **one-cell solution (paste in D1):**

```
={"material", "required", "total";
 ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B, Sheet2!A2:C, {2,3}, 0), )),
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), C2:C*VLOOKUP(B2:B, Sheet2!A2:C, 3, 0), ))}
```

[image]

- **if you want it to export into Sheet3 use:**

```
={{QUERY(Sheet1!A1:C, "select *", 1)},
  {"material", "required", "total";
  ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!B2:B, Sheet2!A2:C, {2,3}, 0), )),
  ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(Sheet1!A2:A), Sheet1!C2:C*VLOOKUP(Sheet1!B2:B, Sheet2!A2:C, 3, 0), ))}}
```

[image]

Comment: This is not a proper left join, VLOOKUP only returns 1 match if multiple matches.

Answer (score 5):

Recently I create a script to do LeftJoin on tables, my script resolve your case. The script join up to 3 right tables, but can be easyli increased to more. So enjoy.

Supose you have all in A1:C5 and E1:G5 data in one sheet. All you need is only put a line like that:

`=LEFTJOIN("A1:C5";"E1:G5"; "A=F";0)`

We can see a working example [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yiHSlu63HsQ8OcnNwsBS4nYC9RcOkUVI0GgLzJ4igBU/edit?usp=sharing)

I used code from Mogsdad@stackoverflow, so thanks him to.

```
/**
 * Convert a cell reference from A1Notation to 0-based indices (for arrays) 
 * or 1-based indices (for Spreadsheet Service methods).
 *
 * @param {String}    cellA1   Cell reference to be converted.
 * @param {Number}    index    (optional, default 0) Indicate 0 or 1 indexing
 *
 * @return {object}            {row,col}, both 0-based array indices.
 *
 * @throws                     Error if invalid parameter
 *
 * @author                     Mogsdad at stackoverflow
 */
function cellA1ToIndex( cellA1, index ) {
  // Ensure index is (default) 0 or 1, no other values accepted.
  index = index || 0;
  index = (index == 0) ? 0 : 1;

  // Use regex match to find column & row references.
  // Must start with letters, end with numbers.
  // This regex still allows induhviduals to provide illegal strings like "AB.#%123"
  var match = cellA1.match(/(^[A-Z]+)|([0-9]+$)/gm);

  if (match.length != 2) throw new Error( "Invalid cell reference" );

  var colA1 = match[0];
  var rowA1 = match[1];

  return { row: rowA1ToIndex( rowA1, index ),
           col: colA1ToIndex( colA1, index ) };
}

/**
 * Return a 0-based array index corresponding to a spreadsheet column
 * label, as in A1 notation.
 *
 * @param {String}    colA1    Column label to be converted.
 *
 * @return {Number}            0-based array index.
 * @param {Number}    index    (optional, default 0) Indicate 0 or 1 indexing
 *
 * @throws                     Error if invalid parameter
 *
 * @author                     Mogsdad at stackoverflow
 */
function colA1ToIndex( colA1, index ) {
  if (typeof colA1 !== 'string' || colA1.length > 2) 
    throw new Error( "Expected column label." );

  // Ensure index is (default) 0 or 1, no other values accepted.
  index = index || 0;
  index = (index == 0) ? 0 : 1;

  var A = "A".charCodeAt(0);

  var number = colA1.charCodeAt(colA1.length-1) - A;
  if (colA1.length == 2) {
    number += 26 * (colA1.charCodeAt(0) - A + 1);
  }
  return number + index;
}


/**
 * Return a 0-based array index corresponding to a spreadsheet row
 * number, as in A1 notation. Almost pointless, really, but maintains
 * symmetry with colA1ToIndex().
 *
 * @param {Number}    rowA1    Row number to be converted.
 * @param {Number}    index    (optional, default 0) Indicate 0 or 1 indexing
 *
 * @return {Number}            0-based array index.
 *
 * @author                     Mogsdad at stackoverflow
 */
function rowA1ToIndex( rowA1, index ) {
  // Ensure index is (default) 0 or 1, no other values accepted.
  index = index || 0;
  index = (index == 0) ? 0 : 1;

  return rowA1 - 1 + index;
}

/**
 * Split a String with Sheet Range A1Notation into Object with Sheet and Range
 *
 * @param {String}    range    Sheet string range in format A1 (ex: Sheet1!A1:C3)
 *
 * @return {object}            {sheet,range}, both 0-based array indices. 
 *
 * @author                     SauloAlessandre at stackoverflow
 */
function SSA1_split_sheet_range(range) 
{
    var sheet_range = range.split('!');
    var sheet_name;
    var range_name;
    if (sheet_range.length == 2) {
        sheet_name = sheet_range[0];
        range_name = sheet_range[1];
    }
    else {
        sheet_name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetName();
        range_name = sheet_range[0];
    }
    return {sheet: sheet_name, range: range_name};
}

/**
 * @param {String}    range    Sheet string range in format A1 (ex: Sheet1!A1:C3)
 *
 * @return {Sheet object}      for the range passed in param
 *
 * @author                     SauloAlessandre at stackoverflow
 */
function SSA1_range(range) {
    var sheet_range = SSA1_split_sheet_range(range);
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheet_range.sheet);
    return sheet.getRange(sheet_range.range);   
}

function RowsLeftJoin_(left_range, right_ranges, joins, tables, right_ordered, skip_header) 
{
    right_ordered = right_ordered || 0;
    skip_header = skip_header || 0;
    debug = function(row) {
//        Logger.log(row);
    }
    var add_right_columns = function(columns, column, row) {
        for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            if (i != column)
                row.push(columns[i]);
        }
    }
    var discover_column = function(column, column_range) {
        var sheet_range = SSA1_split_sheet_range(column_range);
        var range = sheet_range.range.split(":");
        if (range.length != 2)
            throw new Error("Error RANGE should be ex: A1:B, not " + column_range);
        var c1 = cellA1ToIndex(range[0]).col;
        var c2;
        var col = colA1ToIndex(column);
        var match = range[1].match(/(^[A-Z]+)|([0-9]+$)/gm);
        if (match.length != 2)
            c2 = colA1ToIndex(range[1]);
        else
            c2 = cellA1ToIndex(range[1]).col;
        if (col < c1 || col > c2)
            throw new Error("Error JOIN column [" + column + "] is out of range [" + column_range + "]");
        return col-c1;
    }
    var join_right = function(left_range, right_range, right_max, join, search, row) {
        var right_values = SSA1_range(right_range).getValues();
        var compare = join.split("=");
        if (compare.length != 2)
            throw new Error("Error JOIN should be ex: A=B, not " + join);
        var column_left = discover_column(compare[0], left_range);
        var column_right = discover_column(compare[1], right_range);
        var start = 0;
        var end = right_max - 1;
        debug("column_left " + column_left + " column_right " + column_right);
        if (right_ordered) {
            while (start <= end){ 
                var mid = Math.floor((start + end)/2); 
                debug("join_right [" + right_values[mid][column_right] + "] === [" + search[column_left] + "]");
                if (right_values[mid][column_right] === search[column_left]) {
                    debug("join_right found " + search[column_left]);
                    add_right_columns(right_values[mid], column_right, row);
                    return; 
                }
                else if (right_values[mid][column_right] < search[column_left]) {
                    start = mid + 1; 
                }
                else {
                    end = mid - 1; 
                }
            } 
        }
        else {
            for (; start <= end; start++) {
                if (right_values[start][column_right] === search[column_left]) {
                    debug("join_right found " + search[column_left]);
                    add_right_columns(right_values[start], column_right, row);
                    return; 
                }
            }
        }
        debug("join_right not found " + search[column_left]);
    }
    var count_if_not_empty = function(rows) {
        var total = rows.length;
        for (var i = rows.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (!rows[i][0])
                total--;
        }
        return total;
    }
    var range = [];
    var left_values = SSA1_range(left_range).getValues(); 
    var rows_range = left_values.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows_range; i++) {
        var cols_range = left_values[i].length;
        var row = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < cols_range; j++) {
            if (left_values[i][j])
                row.push(left_values[i][j]);
        }
        for (t = 0; t < tables; t++ ) {
            var right_range = right_ranges[t];
            var right_values = SSA1_range(right_range).getValues(); 
            var right_max = count_if_not_empty(right_values);
            var join = joins[t];
            if (row.length > 0) {
                join_right(left_range, right_range, right_max, join, left_values[i], row);
                debug(row);
            }
        }
        if (row.length > 0)
        range.push(row);
    }
    return range;
}

/**
 * Return a LEFT JOINed range between 2 tables, including all data for the left table
 *
 * @param {Range_String}    left_range     left range to join ex: "A1:B15" (all fields go on)
 * @param {Range_String}    right_range    right range to join "C1:D15" (only equal values are visible)
 * @param {String}          join           equal comparator between left and right (ex: A=C)
 * @param {bool}            sorted         indicates when the right range is sorted (good for big tables)
 *
 * @return {Range}          
 *
 * @author                  SauloAlessandre at stackoverflow
 */
function LeftJoin(left_range, right_range, join, right_ordered, skip_header)
{
    return LeftJoinR1(left_range, right_range, join, right_ordered, skip_header);
}

/**
 * Return a LEFT JOINed range between 2 tables (same LeftJoni)
 *
 * @param {Range_String}    left_range     left range to join ex: "A1:B15" (all fields go on)
 * @param {Range_String}    right_range    right range to join "C1:D15" (only equal values are visible)
 * @param {String}          join           equal comparator between left and right (ex: A=C)
 * @param {bool}            sorted         indicates when the right range is sorted (good for big tables)
 *
 * @return {Range}          
 *
 * @author                  SauloAlessandre at stackoverflow
 */
function LeftJoinR1(left_range, right_range1, join1, right_ordered, skip_header)
{
    var joins = [];
    var right_ranges = [];
    joins.push(join1);
    right_ranges.push(right_range1);
    rows = RowsLeftJoin_(left_range, right_ranges, joins, 1, right_ordered, skip_header);
    return rows;
}

/**
 * Return a LEFT JOINed range between 3 tables, including all data for the left table
 *
 * @param {Range_String}    left_range     left range to join ex: "A1:B15" (all fields go on)
 * @param {Range_String}    right_range1   right range to join "C1:D15" (only equal values are visible)
 * @param {String}          join1          equal comparator between left and right 1 (ex: A=C)
 * @param {Range_String}    right_range2   right range to join "C1:D15" (only equal values are visible)
 * @param {String}          join1          equal comparator between left and right 2 (ex: A=C)
 * @param {bool}            sorted         indicates when the right range is sorted (good for big tables)
 * @param {bool}            skip_header    ignore header
 *
 * @return {Range}          
 *
 * @author                  SauloAlessandre at stackoverflow
 */
function LeftJoinR2(left_range, right_range1, join1, right_range2, join2, right_ordered, skip_header)
{
    var joins = [];
    var right_ranges = [];
    joins.push(join1); joins.push(join2);
    right_ranges.push(right_range1); right_ranges.push(right_range2);    
    rows = RowsLeftJoin_(left_range, right_ranges, joins, 2, right_ordered, skip_header);
    return rows;
}

/**
 * Return a LEFT JOINed range between 4 tables
 *
 * @param {Range_String}    left_range     left range to join ex: "A1:B15" (all fields go on)
 * @param {Range_String}    right_range1   right range to join "C1:D15" (only equal values are visible)
 * @param {String}          join1          equal comparator between left and right 1 (ex: A=C)
 * @param {Range_String}    right_range2   right range to join "C1:D15" (only equal values are visible)
 * @param {String}          join2          equal comparator between left and right 2 (ex: A=C)
 * @param {Range_String}    right_range3   right range to join "C1:D15" (only equal values are visible)
 * @param {String}          join3          equal comparator between left and right 3 (ex: A=C)
 * @param {bool}            sorted         indicates when the right range is sorted (good for big tables)
 * @param {bool}            skip_header    ignore header
 *
 * @return {Range}          
 *
 * @author                  SauloAlessandre at stackoverflow
 */
function LeftJoinR3(left_range, right_range1, join1, right_range2, join2, right_range3, join3, right_ordered, skip_header)
{
    var joins = [];
    var right_ranges = [];
    joins.push(join1); joins.push(join2); joins.push(join3);
    right_ranges.push(right_range1); right_ranges.push(right_range2); right_ranges.push(right_range3);
    rows = RowsLeftJoin_(left_range, right_ranges, joins, 3, right_ordered, skip_header);
    return rows;
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to say that there is a small library for SQL joins on google sheets. Functionality is a bit limited (can only join 2 tables for instance), but well, it works out of the box. Check: https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/formulas_by_top_contributors/515924842729

Comment: Please don't use HTML instead of markdown since it **broke** your code (square brackets became links). In any case, the link proves your code worked for you, but it's a locked file so there's no proof it's the same code from here and the code here failed for me with an error.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your Table A were in A1:C, and your Table B were in E1:G. The following array formula would generate the table you indicate (placed anywhere *other than* Columns A:G):

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY({FILTER(A2:C,ISNUMBER(FIND("\"&A2:A&"\","\"&TEXTJOIN("\",TRUE,E$2:E)&"\"))),VLOOKUP(FILTER(A2:A,ISNUMBER(FIND("\"&A2:A&"\","\"&TEXTJOIN("\",TRUE,E$2:$E)&"\"))),QUERY({E$2:G},"Select Col2, Col1, Col3 Where Col1 is Not Null"),{2,3},FALSE)}, "Select Col4, Col1, Col5, Col2, Col3, Col5*Col3 Where Col1 Is Not Null Label Col4 'order_id', Col1 'product_id', Col5 'quantity', Col2 'material', Col3 'required', Col5*Col3 'tot_material'"))`

If it works as you expect, *and* you want to understand it, check back in here. But I do want to make sure it is what you want before diving into explaining something this complex. (If it works and you're happy to just use it without explanation, also fine.)

Answer (score 0):

This forum is more for formulas, but I've found a script in the programming forum that worked for me (while the one here didn't):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66857162/4829915

Answer (score -1):

1. if your second table looks like this:

   [image: 1]
2. and you want something like this:

   [image: 5]
3. then paste this into D2 cell:

   ```
   =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B, Sheet2!A2:C, {2,3}, 0), ))
   ```

   [image: 5]
4. and paste this into F2 cell:

   ```
   =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), C2:C*E2:E, ))
   ```

   [image: 6]

---

---

- if you are not american use: 


  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B; Sheet2!A2:C; {2\3}; 0); ))
  ```




  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A); C2:C*E2:E; ))
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe

```
function MatchbyJOIN() {
  var ss  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var sht = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 1');  
  var rng = sht.getDataRange();
  const a = rng.getValues();
  
  var sht2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 2');  
  var rng2 = sht2.getDataRange();
  const b  = rng2.getValues();
  

  //Match & Postback ALL columns for both arrays
  var result = leftJoin(a, b,"product_id", "order_id")
  
//Or

  //Match & Postback ALL columns of 1st array and SOME columns of 2nd array
  //var result = leftJoin2(a, b, "product_id", "order_id",[2,1])
  
  var sht3 = ss.getSheetByName('output');
  sht3.clear()  
  sht3.getRange(1,1, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result);
 }
}


function leftJoin(a, b, akey, bkey) {
    akey = akey.toLowerCase();
    bkey = bkey.toLowerCase();
  
    const without = ([...array], index) => (array.splice(index, 1), array);
    const aIndex = a[0].findIndex(s => s.toLowerCase() === akey);
    const bIndex = b[0].findIndex(s => s.toLowerCase() === bkey);
    const temp   = b.slice(1).reduce((r, items, i) => (r[items[bIndex]] = items, r), {});
        
    return a.map((a, i) => [
        ...a,
        ...without(
            i
                ? temp[a[aIndex]] || Array(b[0].length).fill('')
                : b[0],
            bIndex
        )
    ]);
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function leftJoin2(a, b, akey,bkey, bcolumns) {
    akey = akey.toLowerCase();
    bkey = bkey.toLowerCase();
  
    const without = ([...array], index) => (array.splice(index, 1), array);
    const aIndex = a[0].findIndex(s => s.toLowerCase() === akey)+1;
    const bIndex = b[0].findIndex(s => s.toLowerCase() === bkey)+1;
    const temp   = b.slice(1).reduce((r, items, i) => (r[items[bIndex]] = items, r), {});
        
    return a.map((items, i) => [
        ...items,
        ...bcolumns.map(
            j => (i
                ? temp[items[aIndex]] || Array(b[0].length).fill('')
                : b[0])[j]                
        )
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Updated Saulo's script

```
/**
 * Convert a cell reference from A1Notation to 0-based indices (for arrays) 
 * or 1-based indices (for Spreadsheet Service methods).
 *
 * @param {String}    cellA1   Cell reference to be converted.
 * @param {Number}    index    (optional, default 0) Indicate 0 or 1 indexing
 *
 * @return {object}            {row,col}, both 0-based array indices.
 *
 * @throws                     Error if invalid parameter
 *
 * @author                     Mogsdad at stackoverflow
 */
function cellA1ToIndex( cellA1, index ) {
  // Ensure index is (default) 0 or 1, no other values accepted.
  index = index || 0;
  index = (index == 0) ? 0 : 1;


// Use regex match to find column & row references.
  // Must start with letters, end with numbers.
  // This regex still allows induhviduals to provide illegal strings like "AB.#%123"
  var match = cellA1.match(/(^[A-Z]+)|([0-9]+$)/gm);



if (match.length != 2) throw new Error( "Invalid cell reference" );



var colA1 = match[0];
  var rowA1 = match[1];



return { row: rowA1ToIndex( rowA1, index ),
           col: colA1ToIndex( colA1, index ) };
}



/**
 * Return a 0-based array index corresponding to a spreadsheet column
 * label, as in A1 notation.
 *
 * @param {String}    colA1    Column label to be converted.
 *
 * @return {Number}            0-based array index.
 * @param {Number}    index    (optional, default 0) Indicate 0 or 1 indexing
 *
 * @throws                     Error if invalid parameter
 *
 * @author                     Mogsdad at stackoverflow
 */
function colA1ToIndex( colA1, index ) {
  if (typeof colA1 !== 'string' || colA1.length > 2) 
    throw new Error( "Expected column label." );



// Ensure index is (default) 0 or 1, no other values accepted.
  index = index || 0;
  index = (index == 0) ? 0 : 1;



var A = "A".charCodeAt(0);



var number = colA1.charCodeAt(colA1.length-1) - A;
  if (colA1.length == 2) {
    number += 26 * (colA1.charCodeAt(0) - A + 1);
  }
  return number + index;
}



/**
 * Return a 0-based array index corresponding to a spreadsheet row
 * number, as in A1 notation. Almost pointless, really, but maintains
 * symmetry with colA1ToIndex().
 *
 * @param {Number}    rowA1    Row number to be converted.
 * @param {Number}    index    (optional, default 0) Indicate 0 or 1 indexing
 *
 * @return {Number}            0-based array index.
 *
 * @author                     Mogsdad at stackoverflow
 */
function rowA1ToIndex( rowA1, index ) {
  // Ensure index is (default) 0 or 1, no other values accepted.
  index = index || 0;
  index = (index == 0) ? 0 : 1;



return rowA1 - 1 + index;
}



/**
 * Split a String with Sheet Range A1Notation into Object with Sheet and Range
 *
 * @param {String}    range    Sheet string range in format A1 (ex: Sheet1!A1:C3)
 *
 * @return {object}            {sheet,range}, both 0-based array indices. 
 *
 * @author                     SauloAlessandre at stackoverflow
 */
function SSA1_split_sheet_range(range) 
{
    var sheet_range = range.split('!');
    var sheet_name;
    var range_name;
    if (sheet_range.length == 2) {
        sheet_name = sheet_range[0];
        range_name = sheet_range1;
    }
    else {
        sheet_name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetName();
        range_name = sheet_range[0];
    }
    return {sheet: sheet_name, range: range_name};
}



/**
 * @param {String}    range    Sheet string range in format A1 (ex: Sheet1!A1:C3)
 *
 * @return {Sheet object}      for the range passed in param
 *
 * @author                     SauloAlessandre at stackoverflow
 */
function SSA1_range(range) {
    var sheet_range = SSA1_split_sheet_range(range);
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheet_range.sheet);
    return sheet.getRange(sheet_range.range);

}



function RowsLeftJoin_(left_range, right_ranges, joins, tables, right_ordered, skip_header) 
{
    right_ordered = right_ordered || 0;
    skip_header = skip_header || 0;
    debug = function(row) {
//        Logger.log(row);
    }
    var add_right_columns = function(columns, column, row) {
        for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            if (i != column)
                row.push(columns[i]);
        }
    }
    var discover_column = function(column, column_range) {
        var sheet_range = SSA1_split_sheet_range(column_range);
        var range = sheet_range.range.split(":");
        if (range.length != 2)
            throw new Error("Error RANGE should be ex: A1:B, not " + column_range);
        var c1 = cellA1ToIndex(range[0]).col;
        var c2;
        var col = colA1ToIndex(column);
        var match = range[1].match(/(^[A-Z]+)|([0-9]+$)/gm);
        if (match.length != 2)
            c2 = colA1ToIndex(range[1]);
        else
            c2 = cellA1ToIndex(range[1]).col;
        if (col < c1 || col > c2)
            throw new Error("Error JOIN column [" + column + "] is out of range [" + column_range + "]");
        return col-c1;
    }
    var join_right = function(left_range, right_range, right_max, join, search, row) {
        var right_values = SSA1_range(right_range).getValues();
        var compare = join.split("=");
        if (compare.length != 2)
            throw new Error("Error JOIN should be ex: A=B, not " + join);
        var column_left = discover_column(compare[0], left_range);
        var column_right = discover_column(compare[1], right_range);
        var start = 0;
        var end = right_max - 1;
        debug("column_left " + column_left + " column_right " + column_right);
        if (right_ordered) {
            while (start <= end){ 
                var mid = Math.floor((start + end)/2); 
                debug("join_right [" + right_values[mid][column_right] + "] === [" + search[column_left] + "]");
                if (right_values[mid][column_right] === search[column_left]) {
                    debug("join_right found " + search[column_left]);
                    add_right_columns(right_values[mid], column_right, row);
                    return; 
                }
                else if (right_values[mid][column_right] < search[column_left]) {
                    start = mid + 1; 
                }
                else {
                    end = mid - 1; 
                }
            } 
        }
        else {
            for (; start <= end; start++) {
                if (right_values[start][column_right] === search[column_left]) {
                    debug("join_right found " + search[column_left]);
                    add_right_columns(right_values[start], column_right, row);
                    return; 
                }
            }
        }
        debug("join_right not found " + search[column_left]);
    }
    var count_if_not_empty = function(rows) {
        var total = rows.length;
        for (var i = rows.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (!rows[i][0])
                total--;
        }
        return total;
    }
    var range = [];
    var left_values = SSA1_range(left_range).getValues(); 
    var rows_range = left_values.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows_range; i++) {
        var cols_range = left_values[i].length;
        var row = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < cols_range; j++) {
            if (left_values[i][j])
                row.push(left_values[i][j]);
        }
        for (t = 0; t < tables; t++ ) {
            var right_range = right_ranges[t];
            var right_values = SSA1_range(right_range).getValues(); 
            var right_max = count_if_not_empty(right_values);
            var join = joins[t];
            if (row.length > 0) {
                join_right(left_range, right_range, right_max, join, left_values[i], row);
                debug(row);
            }
        }
        if (row.length > 0)
        range.push(row);
    }
    return range;
}



/**
 * Return a LEFT JOINed range between 2 tables, including all data for the left table
 *
 * @param {Range_String}    left_range     left range to join ex: "A1:B15" (all fields go on)
 * @param {Range_String}    right_range    right range to join "C1:D15" (only equal values are visible)
 * @param {String}          join           equal comparator between left and right (ex: A=C)
 * @param {bool}            sorted         indicates when the right range is sorted (good for big tables)
 *
 * @return {Range}

 *
 * @author                  SauloAlessandre at stackoverflow
 */
function LeftJoin(left_range, right_range, join, right_ordered, skip_header)
{
    return LeftJoinR1(left_range, right_range, join, right_ordered, skip_header);
}



/**
 * Return a LEFT JOINed range between 2 tables (same LeftJoni)
 *
 * @param {Range_String}    left_range     left range to join ex: "A1:B15" (all fields go on)
 * @param {Range_String}    right_range    right range to join "C1:D15" (only equal values are visible)
 * @param {String}          join           equal comparator between left and right (ex: A=C)
 * @param {bool}            sorted         indicates when the right range is sorted (good for big tables)
 *
 * @return {Range}

 *
 * @author                  SauloAlessandre at stackoverflow
 */
function LeftJoinR1(left_range, right_range1, join1, right_ordered, skip_header)
{
    var joins = [];
    var right_ranges = [];
    joins.push(join1);
    right_ranges.push(right_range1);
    rows = RowsLeftJoin_(left_range, right_ranges, joins, 1, right_ordered, skip_header);
    return rows;
}



/**
 * Return a LEFT JOINed range between 3 tables, including all data for the left table
 *
 * @param {Range_String}    left_range     left range to join ex: "A1:B15" (all fields go on)
 * @param {Range_String}    right_range1   right range to join "C1:D15" (only equal values are visible)
 * @param {String}          join1          equal comparator between left and right 1 (ex: A=C)
 * @param {Range_String}    right_range2   right range to join "C1:D15" (only equal values are visible)
 * @param {String}          join1          equal comparator between left and right 2 (ex: A=C)
 * @param {bool}            sorted         indicates when the right range is sorted (good for big tables)
 * @param {bool}            skip_header    ignore header
 *
 * @return {Range}

 *
 * @author                  SauloAlessandre at stackoverflow
 */
function LeftJoinR2(left_range, right_range1, join1, right_range2, join2, right_ordered, skip_header)
{
    var joins = [];
    var right_ranges = [];
    joins.push(join1); joins.push(join2);
    right_ranges.push(right_range1); right_ranges.push(right_range2);

    rows = RowsLeftJoin_(left_range, right_ranges, joins, 2, right_ordered, skip_header);
    return rows;
}



/**
 * Return a LEFT JOINed range between 4 tables
 *
 * @param {Range_String}    left_range     left range to join ex: "A1:B15" (all fields go on)
 * @param {Range_String}    right_range1   right range to join "C1:D15" (only equal values are visible)
 * @param {String}          join1          equal comparator between left and right 1 (ex: A=C)
 * @param {Range_String}    right_range2   right range to join "C1:D15" (only equal values are visible)
 * @param {String}          join2          equal comparator between left and right 2 (ex: A=C)
 * @param {Range_String}    right_range3   right range to join "C1:D15" (only equal values are visible)
 * @param {String}          join3          equal comparator between left and right 3 (ex: A=C)
 * @param {bool}            sorted         indicates when the right range is sorted (good for big tables)
 * @param {bool}            skip_header    ignore header
 *
 * @return {Range}

 *
 * @author                  SauloAlessandre at stackoverflow
 */
function LeftJoinR3(left_range, right_range1, join1, right_range2, join2, right_range3, join3, right_ordered, skip_header)
{
    var joins = [];
    var right_ranges = [];
    joins.push(join1); joins.push(join2); joins.push(join3);
    right_ranges.push(right_range1); right_ranges.push(right_range2); right_ranges.push(right_range3);
    rows = RowsLeftJoin_(left_range, right_ranges, joins, 3, right_ordered, skip_header);
    return rows;
}
```