# Left join 2 sheets on 2 key values, add constant value

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I'd like to join by date on these 2 sheets (`Income` & `Expense`),  on key values `month` and `day` and add constant value from `FixedCost` sheet,

**Income:**
[image]

**Expense:**
[image]

**Add FixedCost to every row/date:**

[image]

**Desired result, with subtotal on `Dashboard` sheet**:
[image]

**Example sheet:** 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O1rZUstDNSXPdUVXvaDfPO4rAQs2cJWHimfGxbddtNU/edit#gid=1037187610

How can this be done? I've seen the array formula solution, but it looks like an inner join instead of a left join here: [LEFT JOIN two and more tables in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/124595/left-join-two-and-more-tables-in-google-sheets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({Income!A1:E1, Expense!C1:D1, "FixedCost", "SubTotal"; 
 INDIRECT("Income!A2:E"&COUNTA(Income!A2:A)+1),
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("Income!A2:B"&
 COUNTA(Income!A2:A)+1)),,999^99)), 
 {TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Expense!A2:B),,999^99)), Expense!C2:D}, {2, 3}, 0), 0),
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(FixedCost!A2&"♠", COUNTA(Income!A2:A)), "♠")),
 ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(Income!C2:C-IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 INDIRECT("Income!A2:B"&COUNTA(Income!A2:A)+1)),,999^99)), 
 {TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Expense!A2:B),,999^99)), Expense!C2:D}, 2, 0), 0)-
 FixedCost!A2, COUNTA(Income!A2:A), 1)})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: May I ask, without FixedCost & SubTotal, what it would look like? I'm thinking adding those 2 requirements is making it overly complex, I can add those fields separate from the ArrayFormula.. I'm trying to figure out the query but it's tough wrapping my head around it

Comment: it would look like this: `=ARRAYFORMULA({Income!A1:E1, Expense!C1:D1; 
 INDIRECT("Income!A2:E"&COUNTA(Income!A2:A)+1),
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("Income!A2:B"&
 COUNTA(Income!A2:A)+1)),,999^99)), 
 {TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Expense!A2:B),,999^99)), Expense!C2:D}, {2, 3}, 0), 0)})`