# Left Join in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have A and B.

Google working example here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/157x9Yg9tG2pmV-q4wZVn0NW1xas4VSin3zASbrCV3t4/edit?usp=sharing

Sheet A stores data about patients.

[image]

Sheet B contains data about patients' vital signs that are collected.

[image: sheet B]

I need to perform the equivalent of SQL Left Join on these two sheets, using ID column of both sheets as reference, such that the resulting C, would be:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LEFT JOIN two and more tables in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/124595/88163)

Comment: Hi @Rubén, thank you for your comment. It seems so, but I am having difficulties in in adapting this solution for my specific problem. First, how to adjust the formula to add 6 instead of two columns?.Second, I need to make sure the right way to correct regional formatting differences between comma and semicolon in the array formula.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add all the relevant details directly to it including a brief description of your search/research efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following [refactored formula](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/124696/117311) for your needs and your locale (Brazil):

```
={QUERY(SheetA!A1:G1)\QUERY(SheetB!A1:F1);
  QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SheetA!A2:A11; SheetA!A2:G11; {1\2\3\4\5\6\7}; 0); "")))\
  QUERY(IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(SheetA!A2:A11); VLOOKUP(SheetA!A2:A11; SheetB!A2:F11; {1\2\3\4\5\6}; 0); ));""))}
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.