# How to combine multiple sheets and sort the results in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a "main" sheet like this (which is single words, not compound words):

---

[image]

---

And I have a compound word sheet like this:

---

[image]

---

Notice the slightly different columns. How do I combine both lists, aligning them at the `custom` column, and then sort the result (and ideally so it's non-editable)? I can slightly adjust the columns if necessary.

I would like to do it in the 3rd "full" sheet.

I tried this:

```
=SORT({main!A2:D;compound!A2:D},1,TRUE)
```

But it doesn't sort them by the `custom` column, and I'm not sure I have it right.

Comment: Hi. "and ideally so it's non-editable". Would you explain EXACTLY what you mean by this? Would you please also edit your question to display an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: Related: [INNER JOIN in Google Spreadsheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65809201/1330560)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LEFT JOIN two and more tables in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/124595/left-join-two-and-more-tables-in-google-sheets)